# error cannot find module 'balanced-match' in ember

Tags: node.js, ember.js

My installed ember cli version 0.2.7, node: 0.12.2,npm: 2.11.0 while start ember server on my application,It shows following error.

```
Cannot find module 'balanced-match'
Error: Cannot find module 'balanced-match'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
```

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried deleting your node_modules folder, clearing the cache and reinstalling? On a side note you should consider upgrading your ember-cli version 0.2.7 is a long time ago.

Comment: my application on 0.2.7 so only i am using this version

Comment: Reinstall node_modules and show us your package.json file.

Comment: thanks its working fine now..